# How to implement a matrix of unknown size(or any size) in the following code using Typescript

Tags: typescript

Any help is appreciated :)
As mentioned above I would like to implement a matrix possibly of unknown size for example to grow as data grows or it could be a fixed matrix, I just started with typescript so all of this is still pretty much new for me

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook)
{
  /*while (true){*/
    let TrackerSheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Tracker');
    let DataTable = workbook.getTable('Table3');
    let date = new Date(Date.now());
    console.log(date);
    if(/*date.getHours()==17 && date.getMinutes()==0 && date.getSeconds()==0*/ true){
      console.log('Hello');
      
      let range = DataTable.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
      let rownumber = DataTable.getRowCount();
      for(var i=0; i <= rownumber ; i++){
        if (TrackerSheet.getCell(i,4).getValue() == 30 ) {
          TrackerSheet.getCell(i,5).setValue('Notification sent');
          let rangerow = TrackerSheet.getRangeByIndexes(i,0,1,5);
          // Set the fill color to green for the top 10% of values in the range.
          let conditionalFormat = rangerow.addConditionalFormat(ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.topBottom)
          conditionalFormat.getTopBottom().getFormat().getFill().setColor("red");
          conditionalFormat.getTopBottom().setRule({
            rank: 100, // The percentage threshold.
            type: ExcelScript.ConditionalTopBottomCriterionType.topItems // The type of the top/bottom condition.
          });
          
          console.log('Hello again')
        }
      }
    }
 // }
}
``
```